# How to use *.tf or *.tfi files in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-plugins, fme-form, proj

I have some data in a deprecated projection that might not have an EPSG code. I I have asked the provider to tell me which coordinate system is and the answer come with those file, probably to use FME.

The .tf is like this:

```
TRANSFORMATION  stj_lok_sweref991800    2009-03-04 10:14:40 Kempe
Kempe         2009-09-03 GPASS 3.51
Inpassning:   Stj_lok_090903_2.k -> Swe99_lok_090903_2.k
Plan:         KDIFF, 819  punkter.
+   Restfelsinterpolering     TRIAD 4.0   2009-09-03 16:12
+
The parameters are based on a least squares fit using a Transverse Mercator  projection.
Ellipsoid: GRS 80
TRANSVERSE MERCATOR PARAMETERS
Central meridian                18   2   9.348000 degr. min. sec.
Scale along central merdian        1.000025550000
False northing                      -6455066.2870 m
False easting                         133496.8020 m
+
COMPUTATIONAL MODEL
7-parameter transformation vector formula:
   X(to) = DeltaX + (1 + scale_correction) * R * X(from)
where the order of multiplication of the compound rotation matrix R is RZ*RY*RX. RX, RY and RZ being the matrices expressing the rotations a
The numerical values of the seven parameters are:
Translation along X-axis:      -40.0458223192 m
Translation along Y-axis:      128.1224164328 m
Translation along Z-axis:        -.3377596899 m
+
 Överräkning mellan SYSTEM:
 SWEREF 99 lat long-> SWEREF 99 18 00
/
FSYSTEM Södertälje_lokalt/
AREA              70000              80000             130000             130000 /
TSYSTEM SWEREF 99 18 00/
TRIAD   stj_korr.tr1/
SYSTEM Södertälje_lokalt/
ELLIPSOID GRS 80/
PROJ Gauss
G     18   2  9.3480000000 DEG
  -6455066.2870
    133496.8020
    1.000025550000 /
SYSTEM  Fictive lat long/
LATLONG   DEG/
ELLIPSOID GRS 80/
STACK H  /* Save height
Z/
HTRANS ELLIPSOID 0/ /* h=0
GEOCART/
FORMEL CART
BW 7
      -40.0458223192      128.1224164328        -.3377596899
      717.9984439633      228.9888458955     1259.7748095849
         .0159239170
/
ELLIPSOID GRS 80/
CARTGEO/
RETURN H
Z/
SYSTEM SWEREF 99 lat long/
LATLONG   DEG/
ELLIPSOID GRS 80/
PROJ    GAUSS
G 18 00 0 DEG
0
150000
1
/
STOP /
```

Which migh have the information I need, but I do not find any specification of this file.

Is there a way to use the info in this file to build a custom CRS using the proj.4 library?

BTW, I do not need too much precision, so any fair approximation to the meter is fine for my purposes

Comment: It looks like those files form a reprojection instruction set for the GTrans coordinate system transformation tools, part of FME. You can read more about it here: https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/1181/fme-and-the-gtrans-coordinate-system-transformatio.html

Comment: yes you can add custom projections to FME use the MyCoordSysDefs to define your parameters see https://docs.safe.com/fme/2016.1/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Workbench/Workbench/coordinate_sys_custom_about.htm